# proper way to store class instances in python app

Tags: python, class, storage, instances

I am trying to understand what's the best way to store class instances in an app, so that I access the attributes right and invoke each class method right. I would like the solution to work with ORM i.e. SqlAlchemy and add GUI in the end.

Let's say I have Notebook class. There's also Note class that can belong to one Notebook. And there's a Picture class - its instance can appear in multiple Notes that belong to different Notebook instances.

For now I thought of approach below (I've made it simpler/without ORM just to get the idea):

```
class Notebook(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.notesid=[]

    def view_notes(self,notes,pictures):
        for key,item in notes.items():
            if key in self.notesid:
                item.show(pictures)

class Note(object):
    def __init__(self,id,content,picture):
        self.id = id
        self.content = content
        self.picturesid = [picture.id]
    def show(self,pictures):
        print(self.id, self.content)
        for item in pictures:
            if item.id in self.picturesid:
                print(item)

class Picture(object):
    def __init__(self,id,path):
        self.id = id
        self.path = path
    def __str__(self):
        '''shows picture'''
        return "and here's picture %s" % (self.id)

# main program

notesdict={}
pictureslist=[]

notebook1=Notebook()
picture1 = Picture('p1','path/to/file')
note1=Note('n1','hello world',picture1)

notesdict[note1.id] = note1
pictureslist.append(picture1)
notebook1.notesid.append(note1.id)

notebook1.view_notes(notesdict,pictureslist)
```

I am not sure if that's the proper approach as even in this simple example I need to throw all the dictionaries/instance containers into the view_notes() method. It feels like there must be a simplier/less error prone way.

All the articles I find say about class creation but I can't find anything about putting it  all together in an app and "class instances management", storing multiple class instances (with both one-to-many or many-to-many links at the same time) of classes of a different kind.

Could You please direct me to proper thinking/approach either by using the code above/links to articles/books?

Comment: Could you correct the subject line to match the text?  Are you storing classes or instances (objects)?  The distinction matters.  And what do you mean by an `app`?  In other words, in what kind of environment, or OS, are running this code?

Comment: I have changed the subject as suggested. Not sure how the second question matters, but for the 'app' I mean main loop, I will be running it on Windows(but if it is Python interpreter I guess the os doesn't matter?)

Comment: OK, what do you mean by 'store'?  Is the focus on data structures while the 'app' is running, or storing objects longterm (in a file or database)?  In Python lists and dictionaries are the normal structures for collecting objects

Comment: Ok, lets start with non-persistant storing. Where this dictionary/should be created (based on my example)? In the main loop? I don't feel it's a good idea because I would need to pass more and more lists to the methods. Is it how it should be done? I read somewhere that this list can be created inside class, ie here in Notebook class I would create self.notes list/dict if I understand it right. Which approach is better? Or is there another one?

Comment: If logically a `Notebook` contains `Notes`, then I'd give it an attribute (list or dict) that can contain `Note` objects, not just their ids.  And the `Notebook` `__init__` might accept a list of `Notes`.   A `Note` object can be in several collections at once, whether it's a global list, or one of several `Notebook`s.

Comment: Can You explain more the last sentence about instance related to multiple Notebooks? How to store the Note objects then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I understood it.
Class instances can be stored in attributes of list/dictionary type in other class instances (eg Note instance inside Notebook instance).

The important thing to remember is **what actually gets stored** inside that attribute **is reference to the instance located under certain address in the RAM memory, not the instance directly.**

Consider this:

```
class Notebook(object):    
     def __init__(self, iteminstance):
        self.lista = [iteminstance]
     def show(self):
        print('Container1 list:')
        for item in self.lista:
            print(item.content)

class Binder(object):    
     def __init__(self, iteminstance):
        self.lista = [iteminstance]
     def show(self):
        print('Container2 list:')
        for item in self.lista:
            print(item.content)

class Note(object):    
    def __init__(self, txt):    
        self.content = txt    

# create Notebook instance and store Note instance in 'lista' list argument    
a=Notebook(Note(5))    
a.show()    

# assign the same Note instance to different container, Binder instance    
b=Binder(a.lista[0])    
b.show()

# check if both containers include the same object    
print(a.lista==b.lista)
>>>True

# change content of the Note instance via Notebook instance    
a.lista[0].content = 10

# check if content has changed in both Notebook and Binder instances 
a.show()    
b.show()
```

**So after second assignment (to the Binder) what gets copied is actually just the reference to the memory address.**

So every change in the stored object (in Note in this case) is accessible via every Container.
I thought that second assignment would copy the instance at its current state - but it doesn't.

Thanks hpaulj for asking the right questions!
For further reading I need to look up 'collection class' I think.